# Training using multiple GPUs

Tags: returnn

I want to train RETURRN on LibriSpeech dataset using multiple GPUs, but don't know how to do.
Is this possible? I don't see any option to enable it in .config file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You find some [description in the documentation](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multi_gpu.html). It currently uses Horovod, and basically you have to set `use_horovod = True`, but please see the documentation for further details.